# Bash check array membership with regex

Tags: bash, regex, bash-scripting, array

I have just started bash scripting as of this morning, so forgive me for my less-than-adequate skills.

I have a GitHub action where I `scp` files which have changed on a push event to the production server. I am trying to read file names to ignore(*not* `scp` to the server) from a `.txt` file into an array and compare changed file names to the file names in the array, using a regex to determine if the modified filename starts with any of the ignore filenames.
For example, if I have a line in the ignore text file which says `.github`, I want all files that have changed whose paths start with `.github` NOT to be updated.

Here is what I have so far:

```bsh
readarray -d '\n' -t ignoreFiles < .github/doNotUpdate.txt

mapfile -d ',' -t added_modified_files < <(printf '%s,' '${{ steps.files.outputs.added_modified }}')

for added_modified_file in "${added_modified_files[@]}"; do
  for ignore_start_path in $ignoreFiles; do
    echo $ignore_start_path
    if [[ ! $added_modified_file =~ "^${ignore_start_path}.*" ]]; then
      echo "$added_modified_file was modified, uploading to production via SSH"
      scp -i ./key.pem -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $added_modified_file user@host.com:/var/schedule/$added_modified_file
    fi
  done
done
```

The problem is that the series of loops that I have will compare the first `$added_modified_file` and the first `$ignore_start_path`, and if they are different, even if later in `$ignoreFiles` there is an entry that would match `$added_modified_file, it will` scp` a file what was meant to be ignored. I am stumped on how to fix this.

### Main Question:

How can I check if *any* `$added_modified_file` starts with any `$ignoreFile` in the array?

Any help is ***greatly*** appreciated!

Comment: I suggest to move your question to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Is there any particular process for doing so?